# SMTP Relay to Multiple Hosts

Tags: email, exchange, postfix, smtp, route

I have a situation where I need to configure an MTA to relay messages for a single domain (@example.com) to multiple (3) seperate SMTP servers. Email for user@example.com received on SMTP-1 needs to be relayed/routed to SMTP-2, SMTP-3, & SMTP-4. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. The MTA can be anything from Exchange to Postfix. Whatever does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you should be able to create another SMTP connector in 
Exchange for the @example.com address space, give it a lower cost then the default SMTP connector, and configure it to forward all email to SMTP-2, SMTP-3, and SMTP-4 as smarthosts.

Comment: I did as you suggested, however it appears that the Exchange server (2010) is only delivering to the first smart host in the list and ignoring the others. I need to have the mail relayed/routed to all 3 additional smtp servers. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Oh. My apologies, I thought this was Exchange Server 2003. I'm afraid I don't know anything about Exchange Server 2010.

Comment: I'm able to implement an Exchange 2003 server. Are you saying that it would send to all of the configured smart hosts if setup this way in Exchange 2003?

Comment: I've never done it so I can't verifiy it but that's my understanding. Also, I've read bits and pieces about doing it in Exchange Server 2007 so I'm sure it's also possible with Exchange Server 2010. Maybe a little Google fu will help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? That's not a typical request. If the 3 smtp servers play different roles (archiving, spam, av, etc) they're typically setup as a pipeline, not a tree.